# XSLT for-each loop and formatting table rows

Tags: xml, xslt, formatting

How could I modify the xsl below so that in the for-each loop that is placing images puts 2 images per table row, rather than 4 (what it currently does).

I believe it has to do with the mod function?

I tried splitting the foreach sibling loop onto another row but then only the first image shows up on the first row and the rest on a second row.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Finding">
  <xsl:if test="FindingType = 'A'">
  <xsl:variable name="nImage" select="count(Image)" />
    <tr><td class="di"><table width="100%" class="findings">
  <tr><td class="shade" colspan="4"><p class="g"><b>Finding</b></p></td></tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="Image[position() mod 4 = 1]">
<tr><td width="25%" align="left" valign="top"><p class="g"><img src="{.}" height="128" width="128" hspace="12"/><br />
    <xsl:value-of select="@Type" /><xsl:text> </xsl:text>    <xsl:value-of select="@SubType" />
    <xsl:if test="@Position != ''"> (<xsl:value-of select="@Position" />)         </xsl:if><br /><br />
</p>
    </td></tr>
<tr><xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::Image[position() &lt; 4 and (position() mod 4 = 0 or position() mod 4 = 1 or position() mod 4 = 2)]">
    <td width="25%" valign="top" align="left"><p class="g">
    <xsl:if test="(string-length(following-sibling::Image/.) > 0)">
    <img src="{following-sibling::Image/.}" height="128" width="128" hspace="12" />
    </xsl:if>
    <br />
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Image/@Type" />        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>    
    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Image/@SubType" />
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::Image/@Position != ''"> (<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Image/@Position" />)         </xsl:if>
<br /><br /></p>
</td>
</xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:if test="$nImage = 2">
    <td width="25%" />
  </xsl:if>
</tr>
```

Comment: This question is no way to treat your friends...

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution and explanation of a necessary refactoring of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should change `Image[position() mod 4 = 1]` to use 2 instead of 4.
And below `. | following-sibling::Image[position() < 4 and (position() mod 4 = 0 or position() mod 4 = 1 or position() mod 4 = 2)]` becomes `. | following-sibling::Image[position() < 2 and (position() mod 2 = 0)]`.

That should be enough.

Comment: Well, and you'll probably want to change a few instances of 25% to 50%; and while you're cursing the person who wrote this code in such an inflexible way, do your successors the favour of generalizing it by using a variable for the number of columns, rather than hard-coding it.

Comment: @Michael Kay: True. And the expression with `following-sibling::` axis would become `. | following-sibling::Image[position() < $numberOfImagesPerTableRow - 1]`, if I counted right.

Comment: @Alexey-Ivanov: The `and` in the last predicate is unnecessary -- see my answer.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: Yes, I noticed that, see my commet to @MichaelKay. Yet according to the original code `position() < 4` will include `position() = 3`, and the condition in parenthesis selects only values of 0, 1, 2. Therefore I think the predicate in your "Do note" must be `[position() &lt; 3]`.

Comment: @Alexey-Ivanov: No, the correct predicate *is* `position() &lt; 4`. Don't forget that in XPath positions are 1-based, not 0-based.

Answer (score 7):

**The answer is simple**: Replace `4` by `2`, or even better, define a global, parameter `pNumCols` with value `2`.

You will have the following changes:

1. **Add this line** at global level: `<xsl:param name="pNumCols" select="2"/>`
2. **Replace**:

   `<xsl:for-each select="Image[position() mod 4 = 1]">`

with

`<xsl:for-each select="Image[position() mod $pNumCols = 1]">`

.3. **Replace**:

```
<xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::Image
              [position() &lt; 4 
             and (position() mod 4 = 0 or position() mod 4 = 1 
                 or position() mod 4 = 2)]">
```

with:

```
<xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::Image
                               [not(position() >= $pNumCols)]">
```

**Do note**:

```
<xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::Image
              [position() &lt; 4 
             and (position() mod 4 = 0 or position() mod 4 = 1 
                 or position() mod 4 = 2)]">
```

is equivalent to the shorter:

```
<xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::Image[position() &lt; 4 ]">
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the question? Anyways, I did try changing 4 to 2. However that didnt work. Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: @Sean-Toman: Probably you didn't carry out all replacements as per my answer, or changed your source XML documrnt, or something else?